# replace multi words using dictionary

Tags: python

```
import re
dic={}
dic1={}
s="ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR `COUNTRY"
sentence=". ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU"
sentence0=". ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"
sentence2=sentence.split()
sentence1=sentence.split()
for position,char in enumerate(sentence1):    
    dic[(char)]=(position)
for position,char in enumerate(sentence2):    
    dic1[(char)]=(position)
dic.update(dic1)
del dic["."]
print(dic)
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(dic.keys()) + r')\b')
result = pattern.sub(lambda x: dic[x.group()], s)
print(result)
```

When I run the program I have these error TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found.How can I solve it?

Comment: this question looks like you're asking: I have an error, please fix it for me. Try to show your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a string for the `sub` function, to fix that you can either change the dictionary's values to strings:

```
dic1[(char)]=str(position)
```

or change the `lambda` function to:

```
result = pattern.sub(lambda x: str(dic[x.group()]), s)
```